# Docusign create envelope with templateId and set values for fields in given templateid

Tags: docusignapi

We are having an docusign integration implemented for our app. I am making below V2 API call

https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/accountID/envelopes

passing below parameter

```
Array
(
    [status] => sent
    [emailSubject] => event registration waiver
    [templateId] => templateID
    [templateRoles] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [roleName] => Test
                    [clientUserId] => 198128
                    [FullName] => Abraham Ray
                    [emailaddress] => kagok@mailinator.com
                )

        )

)
```

but my fields data in evelope is not coming as prefilled.

can someone help me to understand which all parameters are required to pass set values for custom field tags.

Comment: Use the v2.1 API!!

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, I would use v2.1 and not v2.0. There's no reason for you to use the older version of the API.

Second, your code doesn't show any filling of the tabs, only things you are doing is setting up your recipient information (including what you need for embedded signing)

Here is PHP code that [creates an envelope from a template and fill the tabs](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/set-template-tab-values/) with values. Note that the template has to be set correctly for this to work.

https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php/blob/master/src/Services/Examples/eSignature/SetTemplateTabValuesService.php

```
 $check1 = new Checkbox([
            'tab_label' => 'ckAuthorization', 'selected' => "true"]);
        $check3 = new Checkbox([
            'tab_label' => 'ckAgreement', 'selected' => "true"]);
        $number1 = new Number([
            'tab_label' => "numbersOnly", 'value' => '54321']);
        $radio_group = new RadioGroup(['group_name' => "radio1",
            # You only need to provide the radio entry for the entry you're selecting
            'radios' => [
                new Radio(['value' => "white", 'selected' => "true"]),
            ]]);
        $text = new Text([
            'tab_label' => "text", 'value' => "Jabberwocky!"]);

        # We can also add a new field to the ones already in the template:
        $text_extra = new Text([
            'document_id' => "1", 'page_number' => "1",
            'x_position' => "280", 'y_position' => "172",
            'font' => "helvetica", 'font_size' => "size14", 'tab_label' => "added text field",
            'height' => "23", 'width' => "84", 'required' => "false",
            'bold' => 'true', 'value' => $args['signer_name'],
            'locked' => 'false', 'tab_id' => 'name']);

        # Pull together the existing and new tabs in a Tabs object:
        $tabs = new Tabs([
            'checkbox_tabs' => [$check1, $check3], 'number_tabs' => [$number1],
            'radio_group_tabs' => [$radio_group], 'text_tabs' => [$text, $text_extra]]);

        # Create the template role elements to connect the signer and cc recipients
        # to the template
        $signer = new TemplateRole([
            'email' => $args['signer_email'], 'name' => $args['signer_name'],
            'role_name' => 'signer',
            'client_user_id' => $args['signer_client_id'], # change the signer to be embedded
            'tabs' => $tabs # Set tab values
        ]);
        # Create a cc template role.
        $cc = new TemplateRole([
            'email' => $args['cc_email'], 'name' => $args['cc_name'],
            'role_name' => 'cc'
        ]);

        # Add the TemplateRole objects to the envelope object
        $envelope_definition->setTemplateRoles([$signer, $cc]);
```

Here is the JSON (note some values you have to update):

```
{
    "customFields": {
        "textCustomFields": [{
            "name": "'"${text_custom_fields["name"]}"'",
            "required": "'"${text_custom_fields["required"]}"'",
            "show": "'"${text_custom_fields["show"]}"'",
            "value": "'"${text_custom_fields["value"]}"'"
        }]
    },
    "status": "Sent",
    "templateId": "'"${template_id}"'",
    "templateRoles": [{
        "clientUserId": "1000",
        "email": "'"${SIGNER_EMAIL}"'",
        "name": "'"${SIGNER_NAME}"'",
        "roleName": "signer",
        "tabs": {
            "checkboxTabs": [{
                "selected": "'"${checkbox_tabs["selected1"]}"'",
                "tabLabel": "'"${checkbox_tabs["tabLabel1"]}"'"
            }, {
                "selected": "'"${checkbox_tabs["selected2"]}"'",
                "tabLabel": "'"${checkbox_tabs["tabLabel2"]}"'"
            }],
            "listTabs": [{
                "documentId": "'"${list_tabs["documentId"]}"'",
                "pageNumber": "'"${list_tabs["pageNumber"]}"'",
                "tabLabel": "'"${list_tabs["tabLabel"]}"'",
                "value": "'"${list_tabs["value"]}"'"
            }],
            "radioGroupTabs": [{
                "groupName": "radio1",
                "radios": [{
                    "selected": "'"${radio_tabs["selected"]}"'",
                    "value": "'"${radio_tabs["value"]}"'"
                }]
            }],
            "textTabs": [{
                "tabLabel": "'"${text_tabs["tabLabel"]}"'",
                "value": "'"${text_tabs["value"]}"'"
            }, {
                "bold": "true",
                "documentId": "1",
                "font": "helvetica",
                "fontSize": "size14",
                "height": "23",
                "locked": "false",
                "pageNumber": "1",
                "required": "false",
                "tabId": "name",
                "tabLabel": "added text field",
                "value": "'"${SIGNER_NAME}"'",
                "width": "84",
                "xPosition": "280",
                "yPosition": "172"
            }]
        }
    }, {
        "email": "'"${CC_EMAIL}"'",
        "name": "'"${CC_NAME}"'",
        "roleName": "cc"
    }]
}
```

Comment: I do not want to use PHP SDK. In my new implementation I am using API v2.1 Can you please tell me me with working example of how to create envelope with templateId and value set for all standard and custom fields for templateRole

Comment: You have to use the SDK if you want to use PHP like that, otherwise you have to use JSON

Comment: How can I do this using JSON?

Comment: Do you want to use postman?

Comment: Yes, I can do using postman.

Comment: Added JSON to answer